# A question on the existence of elementary particles with relation to time

Tags: standard-model, elementary-particles

Suppose that the universe started existing at time $t = 0$ and we chose another arbitrary point in time $t =\tau$. Is it true that for every positive real number $\tau$ every single elementary particle of the standard model existed in the universe? Are there any particles in the standard model which did not exist before a certain point in time?

Comment: If you assume that at some point in time the universe consisted only of neutrons, everything else would work out. Each neutron of course consists of 3 quarks.

Comment: No, they did not exist. The standard model particles can be converted to and from other standard particles. Yes, very early in the universe during the plank epoch.

Comment: @BradS Can you provide references to your statement please? Would like to do further reading.

Comment: The reason I posted as a "Comment" and not an answer is because I do not remember the sources. These are things I read months ago from multiple sources. Some(sources) were about the early universe and others about elementary particles in general.  Some general information, as always, is on Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe       then maybe check out:   Edward W. Kolb; Michael S. Turner (1994). The Early Universe.